# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main

Tags: java

when i try to compile this:

```
public class Risk
{
}
class territory 
{

    public static void main (String[]arg) 
    {
        System.out.println ("hi") ; 
    } 
}
```

I get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
```

whats going wrong here?

Comment: This Community Wiki question lists the possible causes of this common problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407250/causes-of-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main-exception-in-thread-main

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What the answer wound up being was that the class i run must contain `main` or else it won't work. i'm posting this because, though other answers give roughly the same information, they don't make it explicit.

Answer (score 3):

The class containing the `main()` function must be public, and you may only define one public class per file.  You'll want to have two separate files `Risk.java` and `Territory.java`.

Risk.java:

```
public class Risk {
}
```

Territory.java:

```
public class Territory 
{

    public static void main (String[]arg) 
    {
        System.out.println ("hi") ; 
    } 
}
```

EDIT:  It turns out this isn't true - I was able to run your initial code with the following command line:

```
java territory
```

But my earlier comments point to the best practice for a real app, such as a Risk game.

Answer (score 1):

What class are you trying to run? If you're using the class `territory`, that will work. `Risk` has no `main` method, though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you figure out why this example causes the same issue?

```
public class Simple {
    public void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Inside function");
    }
}
```

Answer: because main() should be public **static** void!

Answer (score -1):

Could it just be a spacing issue?   Your original post shows no space between the ']' and 'arg'.

Try this:

```
public static void main (String[] arg)
```

or, if that still doesn't work:

```
public static void main (String arg[])
```

Comment: -1 No, both of those are immaterial considerations. (Normally I don't downvote posts, but ones that suggest that formatting changes will make any difference demonstrate a deep misunderstanding of the language.)

Comment: The answer may be wrong, but it doesn't suggest a deep misunderstanding. Whitespace is important.

Comment: @Adrian: Sometimes, yes. (`class Foo` is different from `classFoo`.) Other times, such as here, no. Knowing when it makes a difference is a sign of a competent programmer.

Comment: People don't need to make excuses for down-voting a blatantly wrong answer.  Down-voting incorrect answers encourages people to verify their facts before posting.

Comment: I don't disagree with down-voting the answer (it was wrong). I just feel that suggesting the answerer has a deep misunderstanding is a bit strong.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the the main issue there (it's unclear which class the poster was trying to call).  And, I see now that my answer is incorrect, but disagree with the 'deeper misunderstanding' comment.  Whitespace is important, as is formatting for readability/best practices (if not for compilation in this case).

Comment: @elduff: It's one thing to say formatting is good for readability. It's another to say it changes language semantics. (In a language like Python, formatting does indeed change semantics, but we're talking about Java here.) Being a good programmer means you're able to tell which is which.

Comment: @Adrian: Depends on how you define "deep misunderstanding". To me, if one doesn't understand how code is tokenised in a given language (i.e., in Java, `String[]args` is tokenised the same as `String [ ] args`), that says something about how much they understand the language.