# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496073/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main)

```
public class m
{
    int a; //class variable


    void f1()
    {
       int b=10;
       System.out.println(a);
       System.out.println(b);
    }
}
class B
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      m ob=new m(); //object created
      ob.f1(); //calling f1 method

   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome at Stackoverflow. We would appreciate if you take a *bit* more effort in asking the question the smart way in the future :)

Comment: This Community Wiki question lists the possible causes of this common problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407250/causes-of-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main-exception-in-thread-main

Answer (score 5):

I'll guess.

You are trying to invoke:

```
java m
```

Since you defined you main method in class `B` you should call

```
java B
```

To execute it.

Here's my test:

```
$cat >m.java<<. 
> public class m
> {
>     int a; //class variable
>     void f1()
>     {
>        int b=10;
>        System.out.println(a);
>        System.out.println(b);
>     }
> }
> class B
> {
>    public static void main(String args[])
>    {
>       m ob=new m(); //object created
>       ob.f1(); //calling f1 method
>    }
> }
> .
$javac m.java 
$java m 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
$java B
0
10
$
```

If you see, invoking `java B` prints `0 10`as expected.

Comment: BTW this would be a more aligned Java style format: http://pastebin.com/qPvwVZi1

Answer (score 2):

Main needs to be in the top-level class whose name corresponds to the filename - so if "m" is the name of your file that's where main needs to be. Note that by convention class names start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Not necessarily, the `main` method could be in class `B` it is just, `B` needs to be invoked not `m`

Answer (score 1):

Did you invoke the Java program with `java m`?
The `main` method is defined in the class `B`, not `m`, therefore, you need the `java B` command to invoke it.
It may be confusing if you reasoned by "Same as filename.".

Also, putting two classes in one file may be a bad practice.