# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main

Tags: java, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496073/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main)

I got the above message. The code is as follows:

```
class Test
{
 public static void main(String ar[])
 {
  printf("hai");
 }
}
```

How is this problem caused and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm confused, how did you even compile it? My test: `Sandbox.java:27: cannot find symbol symbol  : method printf(java.lang.String)`

Comment: @Lord: Which only confirms my suspicion that he isn't executing the class he think he is executing :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407250/causes-of-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main-exception-in-thread-main

Answer (score 6):

The class which you're trying to execute doesn't have a `main` method.

Since your `main` method looks syntactically fine, this can have two causes:

1. You're executing the wrong class.
2. The actual class file doesn't contain this code.

The solution is obvious:

1. Make sure that your command is pointing the correct class file, you might have multiple class files with the same name and be sitting in the wrong directory.
2. Make sure that you've compiled the correct source file into the correct class file before, you might have edited one and other and forgot to recompile.

Comment: I see what you meant in other comments, now.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the problem that's causing the current exception (see BalusC's answer), the proper "Hello World" in Java is:

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hai");
    }
}
```

See: [`java.lang.System`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)

Comment: That would only have caused a **different** exception *when* he got the `main` to run.

Comment: The normal convention is by the way to put braces on type declatation :)

Comment: From the basic [arrays tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html): *However, convention discourages this form; the brackets identify the array type and should appear with the type designation.*

Comment: @Balus Oh NVM, I thought you meant the curly braces. on `class Test {`. I just copy and pasted the OP's code, didn't change the brackets. Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

I see your problem, the signature is not correct.
It should be public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: Good observation, but not the cause.

Comment: It's however **syntactically** correct.

Comment: @trashgod : I'm also new in Java, and I don't know it can be written this way. In C# it should be illegal.

Comment: Yea Java lets you do weird stuff like that, although its generally not seen

Comment: You can, but it's discouraged. See BalusC's comment on my answer

Answer (score 1):

It could also be a class path issue which causes Eclipse to get confused and not able to find your class when it tries to run it.  I would look at the Java Build Path in the Project Properties to make sure there are no errors.