# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld

Tags: java, linux, compilation, terminal

I've been working on this for about an hour and thumbing through Q&As on stackoverflow but I haven't found a proposed solution to my problem. I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find any duplicate question with an answer that solved my specific problem.

I am trying to write and compile a java program from terminal for the first time (up until this point I have been using Eclipse for java and VIM for everything else, but I feel its time to switch entirely to VIM). Here is my current HelloWorld code:

```
package main;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

I compile and run using the following commands (specifying the classpath to ensure that isn't the problem):

```
javac -cp "./" HelloWorld.java
java -cp "./" HelloWorld
```

This gives me the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld (wrong name: main/HelloWorld)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:480)
```

I know it is seeing the file HelloWorld.class and trying to access the class HelloWorld because if I change the run command to:

```
java -cp "./" Foo
```

I get an entirely different error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Foo
```

I have tried several dozen pages worth of troubleshooting and come up short, including the following:

[Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540065/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main)

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/mac-cmd.html

`java -version` yields:

```
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

My operating system is LinuxMint and `uname -a` yields:

```
Linux will-Latitude-D620 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:50 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: i thought it would just be javac -cp . HelloWorld.java, didnt think the "./" was needed

Comment: Yields the same exact error message, with or without the '/'

Comment: and javac -classpath . HelloWorld.java doesnt work, i would suggest checking if java is on your classpath

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> package main;

This means that your class resides in the `main` package, and its canonical name is `main.HelloWorld`.

Java requires that package names should also be mirrored in the directory structure. This means that:

1. Your `HelloWorld.java` file should be in a directory named `main`
2. You should execute `javac` and `java` from the directory containing `main`, not from `main` itself
3. The classpath should contain the directory where the `main` directory is, not `main` itself
4. `java` expects the canonical name of the class to execute, so `main.HelloWorld`

So, to recap:

You should have something like `myproject/main/HelloWorld.java`

From `myproject`, run `javac main/HelloWorld.java`

From `myproject`, run `java -cp ./ main.HelloWorld`

Comment: Thank you sir! You are absolutely correct, my problem was with the filesystem! Coming from eclipse I didn't fully understand the classpath and had my java files in the base directory. Once I created a main folder and moved the source files to this folder, the problem was solved!

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem too. Just to add to it, people switching from Windows to Linux might experience this problem (?) because I was fine on Windows 7 and moving to Ubuntu raised this error (I think).

Comment: This should give me a file called "main.class" in "myproject" folder or "HelloWorld.class" in "main" folder?

Comment: @alex A file called `HelloWorld.class` in the `main` folder.

Answer (score 10):

You've put your class in a package named "main", but you're trying to treat it like it isn't in a package. Since you put `package main;` at the top of your source file, you need to put HelloWorld.java in ./main, then run `javac ./main/HelloWorld.java`, followed by `java -cp . main.HelloWorld`.

These commands will get you the working example you're trying to build:

```
mkdir main
echo 'package main; public class HelloWorld { public static void main(String... args) { System.out.println("Hello World"); } }' > main/HelloWorld.java
javac main/HelloWorld.java
java -cp . main.HelloWorld
```

Comment: The compile command here doesn't work. It gives a file not found error.

Comment: All I can suggest is that you mistyped something, because this is how it works. I added some simple commands that will do what you're attempting.

Answer (score 3):

As a beginner you might encounter a very similar scenario where the error output is the same. You try to compile and run your simple program(without having any package set) and you do this:

```
javac HelloWorld.java
java HelloWorld.class
```

This will give you the same java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError since java thinks HelloWorld is your **package** and class your **class name**. To solve it just use

```
javac HelloWorld.java
java HelloWorld
```

See the Java page - [Lesson: Common Problems (and Their Solutions)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/problems/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**
Basically, the Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`:

means, that the class which you are trying to run was not found in the classpath.

**Solution**: you need to add the class or `.jar` file which contains this class into the java classpath. When you are running a java class from the command line, you need to add the dot (.)

```
java YourSingleClass -cp .
```

into the classpath which tells the JVM to search for classes in actual directory.

If you are running a class from a .jar file, you need to add this jar file into the classpath:

```
java org.somepackage.SomeClass -cp myJarWithSomeClass.jar
```

Comment: The important thing to point out here is actually that he's not specifying the fully qualified classname (in his case `main.HelloWorld`)

Comment: Isn't that what I am doing with `javac -cp "./" HelloWorld.java` and `java -cp "./" HelloWorld` ?

Comment: And if I change the run command to `java -cp . main/HelloWorld` I get the `Error: Could not find or load main class main.HelloWorld` error again.