# importing same named packages in java

Tags: java

Consider the following directory structure:

[image]

The two files `main.java` and `maintest.java` are on different locations on disk and yet they declare the same package.

Since they declare the same package name, does this mean they are the in the (virtually)same package i.e. java compiler views them as one package and treats them as such, or are they differentiated in some way, if so how?

Also, considering that we declared a static method called `printdate` in main.test, how would we import the `main.java`'s public class and use the `printdate` method in `maintest.java`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132602/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-helloworld)

Comment: With that structure, the classes are in package `xyz`, not in package `com.ge.xyz`.

Comment: oops, sorry my bad, I'll nest the folder structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that `directory1` and `directory2` are on the classpath, then yes `Main.java` and `Maintest.java` are in the same package. The filesystem layout doesn't matter in these cases (except the package structure must match the directory structure, in your picture it doesn't). You could also have a jar file on the classpath containing more files belonging to the same package.

You import and use them as you do normally with any classes.